# RGB array to buffer image in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I have an array consists of the RGB objects (pixel color). Example:

```
[
    {r: 40, g: 143, b: 54},
    {r: 86, g: 193, b: 87},
    ...
]
```

And I have image resolution. Example:

```
{
    width: 400,
    height: 300
}
```

How to convert this array to the Buffer in Node.js to display in a browser?

Comment: What do these RGB objects represent? Is it a list of pixels in the image?

Comment: While you can put the image data into a Buffer like `ArrayBuffer` using `UInt8ClampedArray` you will not be able to directly use that to send an image. You need some image encoding library to create an image stream like jpg or png.

Comment: @zlumer Yes, color of pixel.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank! What library I need?

Comment: [node-jpeg](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-jpeg) (which has a link to node-png) is near the top of search results. Also try searching for "libjpg node.js"

Comment: Depending on what you are developing, you might want to use html5 canvas to build the image using your RGB array data & size parameters. A for (width) loop inside a (height) for loop to paint each pixel following you arrays structure.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1. Convert array of RGB objects to array of bytes.

   ```
   function RGBtoArr(rgb)
   {
       return [rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b];
   }
   function flattenArray(arr)
   {
       return [].concat.apply([], arr);
   }
   var buf = new Buffer(flattenArray(arr.map(RGBtoArr)))
   ```
2. Encode resulting bytes to a browser-supported image format.

   ```
   var png = new Png(buf, width, height);
   png.encode();
   ```
3. Send the resulting image to user (any of the following).

   - Embed the image in base64 into HTML.
   - Save as a png on disc and get an URL to use.
   - Send as a dynamic response on an HTTP request at a certaing URL.

Comment: Question, doesn't this require node-png? Also how would you then display this in the UI? Use a file?

Comment: what is this Png class?